# Query for Fusion Tables doesn't work on Google Maps JS API v3

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to query a fusion tables and display it on my google maps app with cordova.

My problem is that the queries I send are not recognized and the whole table is returned no matter what I put in 'where' constraints.

```
query: {
    select: 'Koordinat',
    from: '1xkSyi8Wew5jBU4CCk1dKNaFS6UEd4bz0_gdkhXhC',
    where: "Ikon = '6'"
}
```

I tried changing the field type between number and text and tried using double and single quotes it the where clause, yet it simply displays all rows on the map.

The fiddle is as follows:
https://jsfiddle.net/mdokur/fnxjzL61/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this query is not valid

```
where: 'Ikon = 1 OR Ikon = 4 OR Ikon = 5 OR Ikon = 8 OR Ikon = 10 OR Ikon = 11 OR Ikon = 12',
```

See [Row and Query SQL Reference](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/sql-reference):

> "OR is not supported. (If you are looking for OR, consider the IN
>   operator. It will do the trick in certain queries)".

So it should be

```
where: 'Ikon IN (1, 4, 5, 8, 10, 11, 12)',
```

Comment: This did solve the problem, however it doesn't explain why my query using 'OR' works elsewhere.

Comment: What query exactly?